# Is there a jquery plugin to use placeholders to show the format of textfield in the form?

Tags: jquery, format

I am seeking a jquery plugin to show the format of a textfield, like "_ _ _ */* _/_ _" to imply to the user that it should be filled with a date. Does anybody konws any plugin?

Comment: Try this: http://www.conetrees.com/2009/03/blog/jquery-masked-input-plugin-increase-usability-for-masked-format-input-fields/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to fit:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Otherwise, you could set the background on the input and disappear it on focus.

If you really want to get fancy, you could break it into three inputs (lots of larger apps do this) and use JS to jump a user's cursor to the next one when one's charlimit is reached.